# change value in stack assembly

Tags: assembly

I want to xor every byte from esi with 0x63. But I'm getting error. How can I fix it?

```
 global _start:
    _start:
jmp short shell
decode:
    mov al, 0x63 ; key
    xor ecx, ecx    
    mov ecx, 21 ; len
    pop esi
    dec:
        xor byte [esi], al
        inc esi
        loop dec
    jmp short code    
shell:
    call decode
code:
     db 0xd3,0x68,0x31,0x0b,0x4c,0x4c,0x10,0x68,0x0b,0x4c,0x01,0x0a,0x0d,0xea,0x80,0x31,0x30,0xea,0x82,0xae,0xe3
```

See the image:

[image: Error Deatils image]

Comment: Why are you clearing `%ecx` before setting it?

Comment: It probably crashes because you're trying to modify read-only memory (specifically the `.text` section).

Comment: Just to be sure that it is clear. I thought that if I don't clear it manually something may go wrong.

Comment: Then why aren't you clearing `%al` before `mov`ing a value into it?

Comment: `xor byte [esi], 0x63` would save more code-size.  IDK why you're messing around with `al` at all.  Or `xor dword [esi], 0x63636363` to make it run faster, doing 4 bytes at a time.  (And BTW, in GDB you can use `set disassembly-flavor intel`)